# process_exception() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: django, exception, middleware

Using Django's latest branch 1.10, I get the mentioned exception when writing a custom middleware class.

Exception: *process_exception() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)*

Stripped down code for the custom middleware looks like this:

```
class CustomMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # do something ...
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_exception(request, exception):
        # do something ...
        return None
```

Accordin gto the latest docs, `process_exception` takes two arguments:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception

The `self` argument that was requiered up to Django 1.9 was dropped. The error is raised within Django itself in *\django\core\handlers\base.py in process_exception_by_middleware*

When adding the previously required `self` argument to my `process_exception` method, it all works. Is this a Django bug - or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: How are you calling the function? If in an object.process_exception() format then you are passing it a "self" argument whether it needs it or not. Adding "self" back to the def process_exception() simply tells it to expect that third argument

Comment: `self` was never explicitly documented (for any method signature, for that matter), but it is required. This is just how python works: all methods accept the instance as the first positional argument.

Comment: I'm not calling it directly at all. Django calls the method in case an error occurs somewhere. And according to the Django docs, self is no longer there as an argument. Please check the Django docs link given in the question. So, I'm confused.

Comment: @knbk: Yes, I saw that construct here and there. It's a bit confusing, especially given that the `__call__` method does require `self` as an extra argument. I just accept it. Thanks!

Comment: The difference is that the documentation of `__call__` provides a working code snippet, so it has to include `self`. The documentation of `process_exception` only provides the call signature, not working code, and omits the `self` argument since it is implied by it being an instance method.